# map transformation on Spark paired rdd

Tags: apache-spark, sparkcore

I applied map transformation on below paired RDD:

```
sc.parallelize(List((1,10),(2,20),(3,30),(4,40)));
```

with two different signatures.

***case 1:***

```
res0.map({case (x,y)=>(x,y+1)}).collect;
```

**which gives below result:**

```
Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,11), (2,21), (3,31), (4,41))
```

***case 2:***

```
res0.map(case (x,y)=>(x,y+1)).collect;
```

**Which gives below error:**

> error: illegal start of simple expression

May I know the reason for ***case 2*** failure, just flower bracket is the difference between two cases.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Case requires {}. In general { case arg => logic } is what is known as a Partial Function in Scala.

You can also do this BTW:

```
val y = RDD.map(a=> (a._1, a._2 + 1)).collect
```